# ALB Ingress Return fixed response 503 not pointing to my services

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

Hello im new to kubernetes ,  just want to ask why my ALB Ingress not pointing to my services when access through url , it just return fix response 503

This is my ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "shortenurl-ingress"
  namespace: "shortenurl-ingress"
  labels:
    app: shortenurl-ingress
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: shortenurl-ingress
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: eks-cluster-sg-shortener-eks-895573458
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/inbound-cidrs: 0.0.0.0/0
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: fuadariqoh.com

spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - host: fuadariqoh.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: shortenerapp
                port:
                  number: 31674
```

this is my service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: shortenerapp
  labels:
    app: shortenerapp
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: shortenurl-app
  ports:
    - port: 31674
      targetPort: 5001
      protocol: TCP
```

this is my deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: shortenurl-app
  labels:
    app: shortenurl-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: shortenurl-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: shortenurl-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: shortenurl-app
          image: imageUri
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5001
```

this is my
[load balancer on aws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41RyO.png)

I cant figure out what i do wrong, any help is appreciated , Thank you.